# Analysis Services: which processing options to choose

Tags: sql, service, ssas

I'm new to Analysis Services and currently I have to reprocess a dimension because some records in the dimension table were updated. I'm not sure which processing options to choose, Process Full or Process Data. If I choose Process Data, do I have to reprocess all the cubes as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [detailed explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karang/archive/2011/01/25/kind-of-ssas-processing-in-simple-words.aspx) of different kindes of cube processing.